# Passing onChange event from mapped child to parent's state returns 'undefined' error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello [from react beginner].
Trying to pass child's input value to parent state.

So, App has an array:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        data: [
            {id: 1, name: 'john'},
            {id: 2, name: 'doe'},
        ]
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <List data={this.state.data}/>
        )
    }
}
```

Then List takes prop.data as state.data and returns children in map:

```
class List extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: this.props.data
        };
        this.parentChange = this.parentChange.bind(this);
    }

    renderList() {
        const data = this.state.data;
        let list = null;

        if (data.length) {
            list = data.map(function(item, index){
                return (<Item key={item.id} data={item} onChange={(e, index) => this.parentChange(e, index)} />)
            });
        } else {
            list = <p>nothing here</p>
        }
        return list;
    }

    parentChange(value, index) {
        // pls give me anything
        console.log('--- value: ', value);
        console.log('--- index: ', index);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.renderList()}</div>
        )
    }
}
```

And Item child:

```
class Item extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {id, name} = this.props.data;

        return (
            <div>
                <input id={id} value={name} onChange={(e) => this.props.onChange(e, id)} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

But if I change any input's value there is an error as result

`Cannot read property 'parentChange' of undefined`

Thanks for any help (code, links etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring a function with **function** keyword:

```
if (data.length) {
  list = data.map(function(item, index){
         return (<Item key={item.id} data={item} onChange={(e, index) => 
                this.parentChange(e, index)} />)
  });
}
```

Declaring a function with the **function** keyword will create another context inside itself, so your **this** (context) will no longer be the **class** context.

The IDE might not warn you but when it runs, JS create another context inside your **function** result in an undefined error.

**So it will need to change to:**

```
if (data.length) {
  list = data.map((item, index) => {
         return (<Item key={item.id} data={item} onChange={(e, index) => 
                this.parentChange(e, index)} />)
  });
}
```